# Cannot activate "deploy and run" plugin

Tags: remix

I'm completely new to blockchain development and remix.

It's my first time ever using Remix. Apparently "Deploy and run transactions" plugin is already activated by default. However, the deploy icon is not visible on the left pane on Remix. Nothing changes after clicking on "deactivate". When I clicked on Permissions, i got the message "No Permission requested yet."

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

checking out on Remix after a few hours passed, the deploy icon now appears on my page perhaps due to the fact that I deactivated and re-activated numerous times. Maybe the tip is to close your browser, refresh the page, (and wait for some time), and try again.